# li not being created from this JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax

Currently I am working on a project that involves taking an input, get some data, and then display data in a list under the input.

I can receive the string from the input into my controller (c#) but the returned json isn't being created into a list on the web page.

What I am expecting is after the input is entered and submitted, it will return the results of a query to the page. In the form of a list.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SoftwareNameResults(ReportModel report) {
  list.Add(report);
  return Json(new { name = report.SoftwareName });
}
```

JS and HTML

```js
function getSoftwareNames() {
  var name = document.getElementById("softwareName").value;
  var stuff = {
    SoftwareName: name
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("SoftwareNameResults","Report")",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(stuff),
    success: function(response) {
      document.getElementById("softwareName").value = "";
      document.getElementById("processName").value = "";

      var list = document.getElementById("softwareList");
      var listItem = document.createElement("li");
      listItem.textContent = response.SoftwareName;
      list.appendChild(listItem);;
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
      alert(errMsg);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
@model ProjectName.Web.Models.ReportModel
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
    <div class="card">
      <h5 class="card-header">Process Report</h5>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <form>
            <div class="col">

              <label class="card-text" style="display: inline-block;">Software Name (Add-/Remove Programs)</label>
              <input type="text" id="softwareName" class="input-group-sm mb-3" />
              <button type="submit" onclick="getSoftwareNames()">Search</button>

            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <label class="card-text" style="display: inline-block;">Process Name</label>
              <input class="input-group-sm mb-3" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-4">
            <label class="card-body">Software Name Results:</label>
            <ul id="softwareList">

            </ul>

          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <label class="card-body">Process Name Results:</label>
            <ul id="processList">

            </ul>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not very skilled with Javascript, trying to get better but this has me stumped.

Comment: When you use your browser's debugging tools to step through the code, is the `success` callback function invoked?  Stepping through that function as it executes, does each variable contain what you expect?  Does each operation produce the result you expect?  Which one first doesn't?  Why is `response` not even used?  Can you narrow this down to the specific client-side operation(s) which fail(s)?

Comment: Indeed. You send stuff and receive the response. You want to access the values in the response and not stuff when your Ajax returns

Comment: You've updated the code... Have you also re-tested?  When you debug, what does `response` actually contain?  The server-side code implies that it has a property called `name`, not `SoftwareName`.  Is this just an ongoing series of typos on your part?

Comment: Nothing has changed after the change in code. It gets to the the response and the value is passed but nothing else excutes afterwards. I will try to update with what I see in browser.

Comment: submit buttons submit forms. You do not cancel the form submission

Comment: Found that the process attempts to create a listed item but then the item disappears part way through. Could it be that since I am rendering it via js that it is not staying rendered?

Comment: @JWright92: *"but then the item disappears part way through"* - Are you observing that the page is reloading?  If so then it's most likely because you're submitting the form.  You can change the `<button>` type to `"button"` instead of `"submit"`, you can remove the `<form>` element entirely, and/or you can cancel the form submission with JavaScript.

Comment: @David you are correct... that Fixed my problem, I had it as a form so it was just reloading the page every time! Thanks for all the help! I am backend developer trying to frontend...